# How does JavaScript array get item at index works

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I'm trying to understand how the `get item at index` works in an array in JavaScript.

For example imagine I have a `for` iterating an array with thousands (or millions) of items. Which would be the best way (with the best performance) to print the items?

```
// Option 1
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var data = array[i];
    console.log( data.ID, data.name, data.date, data.description );
}

// Option 2
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log( array[i].ID, array[i].name, array[i].date, array[i].description );
}
```

Is it option 1 or option 2? Or is it the same thing to use the first or second option? Or is there an even better way to do this?

I know for instance that `get()` in the Java ArrayList works this way, so obviously the best approach would be option 1, since it checks the range each time it calls the `get()` method.

```
public E get(int index) {
    rangeCheck(index);

    return elementData(index);
}

private void rangeCheck(int index) {
    if (index >= size)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(index));
}
```

Does JavaScript works in a similar way?

The "big question" here is really *how does JavaScript array get item at index works*

Note: I've tried to search for the best way to get an element in an array, but all I could find was the best way to iterate an Array. That isn't what I'm trying to get from this question!

Comment: This depends on what do you mean by "print". If it means `console.log`, then the best way is apply `console.log` at whole array: `console.log(array)`, or ``console.log(jSON.stringify(array))``

Comment: Since there are a few engines that execute JS, your question can't be answered entirely. The answer is that it's absolutely irrelevant. However, to conclude in real-world scenario which is better - why don't you measure it yourself? Just take 3 most popular browsers and profile what executes the fastest. I think that you shouldn't even waste your time on this optimization, it's absolutely pointless.

Comment: The way to test would be to create a timer, try both with dynamically generated arrays, and console.log out the resulting times.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

Forget everything I've said. It was true for very old browsers. For the new ones (tested with Chrome, Firefox, IE11 and Edge), there is almost no difference between any of those examples.

I've tested with an array of 100 million records, and the difference is < 1ms.

The Option 2 apparently is *slightly* faster, nothing that will really count.

Comment: Browsers optimize `for` loops over arrays. You likely won't find any performance difference caching the length.

Comment: Your second example will stop the loop when the element is false or 0 or an empty string.

Comment: @torazaburo Sure, it will stop with any falsy values. That's why I've said that he must ensure his objects are not null / undefined (since he's working with objects, not strings, or booleans, or numbers.